# AS3 array length bug

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, debugging

I just found this strange result on the length of an array .
When the table a single number as input, AS3 returns the value of the array as length and not its actual length

For exemple.

```
var test_array:Array = new Array(1908);
trace(test_array.length)
//output 1908
```

But with multiples entries

```
var test_array:Array = new Array(1908,1909);
trace(test_array.length)
//output 2
```

Does anyone have the same bug ?
And where can we ask to fix it if needed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not a bug

`new Array(1908);` is a function that creates an array with 1908 fields

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

> Array(... values) Lets you create an array that contains the specified
>   elements.
>          Array(numElements:int = 0) Lets you create an array of the specified number of elements.

With as3 arrays, you're better of using a different constructor

instead of `var test_array:Array = new Array(1908);`
use `var test_array:Array = [1908];`

and instead of `var test_array:Array = new Array(1908,1909);`
use `var test_array:Array = [1908,1909];`

using this syntax `[]` instead of `new Array()` has less overhead, and is faster

Comment: thank you for your reply , was strange a bug on the array length ..
(But I don't understand why we can define the array length.. is it for memory.. and the length is fixed ?)